# JNI Could not find or load main class- Unique issue

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I tried lot of options to fix this , but could not find a solution. I have created the header file and the dll too. Set the class path asd well. Javac command works fine. When I run this file, I get error: Could not find or load main class com.log.jni.example.HelloWorld. Could you please help me. Here is my file.

```
  public class HelloWorld {
  private native void print(String path);
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String path="C:\\Capture.pcap";
    new HelloWorld().print(path);

}
static {
    System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld");
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you're trying to run this code? Also what package is in? Also show the exact error message.

Comment: I am trying to run from eclipse, and the error message is: "Could not find or load main class com.log.jni."

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that your static initializer is failing.

The following code:

```
public class Main 
{
    static
    {
        if (true)
            throw new Error("Error is here");
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        System.out.println("I am running");
    }
}
```

produces the output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Error is here
    at Main.<clinit>(Main.java:22)
Could not find the main class: Main.  Program will exit.
```

Are there any stack traces printed out before the 'Could not find main class' error?  In this example, the class was found but failed to initialize because of the exception thrown in the static initializer.  In your code, a likely suspect is that the System.loadLibrary() call fails with an `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

Answer (score 0):

The error "Could not find or load main class ..." occurs when the binary file is not built.  Click on project, turn off automatic build.  Then click on project and build all.  Then turn on automatic build.